# Background not visible due to positioning

Tags: html, css, position

The background color of `<ol`> list is not displayed properly. This problem started after I floated label left and input right. How to fix this. The expected result is:

[image]

Here is my result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ3nM/1/

Similarly I've problem with the `div .wrapper`. The shadow should be way below the content and there should be a white color background beneath `<div class=.col-2>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code and added a third <li> with the following style:

```
clear:both;
```

Your float was taking elements out of the document flow and this the background color didn't know where to end.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the float, before you close your `<ol>`

Check it out [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ3nM/4/).

Answer (score 1):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ3nM/5/

Whenever you float things you must clear them at the end so that it can calculate the height properly

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested you can clear the floated content - although this will add another element. You can also add

```
li{overflow:auto;}
```

which will prevent the list from collapsing. In IE6 you will also need the rule

```
li{height:1px;}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ3nM/9/. This method does not require a clearing element.